# How can I run a "middleware" function before a route method is executed?

Tags: backbone.js

Say I have a backbone router like:

```
routes:
  ""                          : "homepage"
  "catalog/:id"               : "catalogPage"
  "catalog/:id/products/:id2" : "productPage"

homepage   :           -> doStuff()
catalogPage: (id)      -> doOtherStuff()
productPage: (id, id2) -> doEvenMoreStuff()
```

and a function:

```
executeBefore = -> console.log("hello")
```

If I want executeBefore to be called and executed each time a route is called and before the corresponding route method, is there a simple way to do it apart from inserting a call to executeBefore at the beginning of every route method ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can override the `route` function in your router class to intercept the route calls :

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "" : "homepage",
        "catalog/:id" : "catalogPage"
    },

    route: function(route, name, callback) {
        var router = this;
        if (!callback) callback = this[name];

        var f = function() {
            console.log('route before', route);
            callback.apply(router, arguments);
            console.log('route after', route);
        };
        return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(this, route, name, f);
    },

    homepage: function() {
        console.log("homepage");
    },
    catalogPage: function(id) {
        console.log("catalogPage "+id);
    }
});

var r = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/EdLzh/

Comment: This solution works well. That said the docs refer to an 'execute' method that should provide similar functionality (albeit at runtime). Doesn't work for me - has anyone else had any luck with it?http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute

Comment: I wanted to save the current route hash before the actual route change. Used above solution but in url hash is changed and then the 'f' function called. So the route is now the new hash and no way to get the old hash. Any idea what might i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

Since Feb, 13, 2014, you can use `router.execute(callback, args, name)` (http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute) for this.

So your interceptor will be looked something like this

```
routes: {
    '': 'homepage',
    'catalog/:id': 'catalogPage',
    'catalog/:id/products/:id2': 'productPage'
},
execute: function(callback, args, name) {
    // Do your stuff here
    executeBefore();

    if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
}
```

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/791033dc1aab53e9e5c9366f64a854224f851231

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [backbone.routefilter](https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter) plugin.

you'll be able to set a filter for all routes

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "index",
    "page/:id": "page"
  },
  before: function( route, params ) { ... },
  after: function( route, params ) { ... },
  index: function(){ ... },
  page: function( route ){ ... }
});
```

Or select some routes

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "index",
    "page/:id": "page"
  },
  before: {
    "": function( route ) { ... },
    "page/:id": function( route ) { ... }
  },
  after: function( route ) { ... },
  index: function(){ ... },
  page: function( route ){ ... }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can play with the Events :

```
Backbone.history.on('route', function () {
    // Do your stuff here.
    executeBefore();
});
```

> visiting #help/uploading will fire a route:help event from the router.

Apparently, this would be triggered before the redirection :

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1243

```
Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
    var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
    callback && callback.apply(router, args);
    router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
    router.trigger('route', name, args);
    Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
});
```

Comment: I think your answer is wrong because if one uses Backbone router by calling router.navigate(route, options); will first execute the route callback and the event 'route' callback. I tested this myself. Sorry for not providing a fiddle.