# Backbone Marionette middleware only runs on first route load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to add some middleware to Marionette's extended version of Backbone's router. Here's my code.

```
AppName.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes:{
        // routes
    },
    route: function(route, name, callback) {
        var router = this;
        if (!callback) {
            callback = this[name];
        }
        var middleware = function() {
            console.log('in middleware');
            callback.apply(router, arguments);
        };
        return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(this, route, name, middleware);
    }
});
```

What I think should be happening is whenever I load a route, the console prints 'in middleware'.

What is happening is whenever I load the first route and only the first route, the console prints 'in middleware'.

I researched by using the top solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942566/how-can-i-run-a-middleware-function-before-a-route-method-is-executed) question and these are the results that I get.

Edit: I have also tried 'execute' as specified in the documentation and have had the same results.